# Опросник на Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, структуры, vuex

Хочу сделать опросник по типу такого [(Опросник)](http://www.flaris.ru/brief/site.html) на Vue.js. Проблема заключается в том что есть большое количество инпутов

Не могу определится и понять как правильнее всего сделать структуру сайта. При использовании компонентного подхода, при извлечении данных будет достаточно проблематично. При использовании Vuex, так же не будет просто. Ну а заваливать data без компонентов кажется вообще бредом, он будет просто перегружен, и разобраться в коде будет крайне проблематично..
Как правильнее всего организовать структуру такого приложения?

---

Вот пример одного блока вопросов сделанных в `data`, а их может быть более 20

```
  data() {
return {
  questions: [
    {
      title: "My Title",
      description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
      textInputs: [
        {
          label: "MyInputLabel",
          value: ""
        },
        {
          label: "Другой текст",
          value: ""
        }
      ],
      checkboxes: [
        {
          label: "Checkbox 1",
          value: false
        },
        {
          label: "Checkbox 2",
          value: false
        }
      ]
    }, ... 
  }
}
```

Разобраться в этом ужасе будет крайне проблематично ;(

Comment: вопрос слишком общий, не имеет точного ответа. Как Вам удобно, так и организовывайте

Comment: В этом и вопрос, как бы вы организовали такую структуру.

Comment: От составления данных в нужном формате, Вам все равно никуда не деться. То ли это будет на сервере, то ли на фронте, но это все равно должен будет кто-то сделать. На счет компонентов: я бы создал что-то типа `Vinput`, `Vcheckbox`, которые бы могли отрисовывать как 1 инпут, так и несколько. Потом бы все это собрал в компоненте-обертке...

Comment: Для начала нарисуй общию структуру. Данные будут в 1 json лежать и разбиты по ключам типа test1, test_2. и каждом тесте будет по хитрому все лежать или они между собой все похожи будут, только где то данных больше, а где-то меньше.